# How to run SQLITE in a Windows Mobile Application developed with Qt

Tags: qt, sqlite, windows-mobile

I am trying to run a simple SQLITE application on Windows Mobile developed with Qt. However I can't manage it, though I have developed other Windows Mobile apps with Qt. The fundamental error is Mobile Device/Emulator can't find SQLITE driver, as I get "Driver not found" error and the following code snippet proves it as well:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QtDebug>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
   QCoreApplication app( argc, argv );

// returns true on mobile platform and false on desktop app.
qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers().empty();

}
```

I would be appreciated if you can answer the followings:

1) Do I have to specify any flag in order to use SQLITE along with it, while configuring Qt. such that: **configure -qt-sql-sqlite**? 
what **configure -help** indicates for those flags:

> ```
> -qt-sql-<driver> ... Enable a SQL <driver> in the Qt Library.
> -plugin-sql-<driver> Enable SQL <driver> as a plugin to be linked to
> ```
>
> at run time.
>                            Available values for :
>                              mysql
>                              psql
>                              oci
>                              odbc
>                              tds
>                              db2  +                         sqlite
>                              sqlite2
>                              ibase
>                            (drivers marked with a '+' have been detected
>   as available on this system)

and this Windows Ce/Mobile specific one:

```
Qt for Windows CE only:

        -no-iwmmxt ......... Do not compile with use of IWMMXT instructions
     +  -iwmmxt ............ Do compile with use of IWMMXT instructions (Qt for Wind
    ows CE on Arm only)
     *  -no-crt ............ Do not add the C runtime to default deployment rules
        -qt-crt ............ Qt identifies C runtime during project generation
        -crt <path> ........ Specify path to C runtime used for project generation.
        -no-cetest ......... Do not compile Windows CE remote test application
     +  -cetest ............ Compile Windows CE remote test application
        -signature <file> .. Use file for signing the target project
        -opengl-es-cm ...... Enable support for OpenGL ES Common
        -opengl-es-cl ...... Enable support for OpenGL ES Common Lite
        -opengl-es-2 ....... Enable support for OpenGL ES 2.0
     *  -phonon-wince-ds9 .. Enable Phonon Direct Show 9 backend for Windows CE
```

2) Which additional files/libs/dlls am I supposed to add during the deployment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re configuring the package with **-sql-sqlite** is sufficient[ in fact I typed 
 ***configure -platform win32-msvc2005 -xplatform wincewm60professional-
msvc2005 -qt-sql-sqlite*** ] to resolve the problem. Otherwise, it will be built with **-plugin-sql-driver** flag - I don't know why this one doesn't work.